# How do I insert an array inside an empty array in PHP?

Tags: php

I have `Values[]`, now, in values I would like to add an entry that looks like this:

```
'name' => 'aa', 'surname' => 'bb'
```

How would I do this?

I know how to do this using `array(entry)` but doesn't this create a new array?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Comment: `$values[] = ['name' => 'aa', 'surname' => 'bb'];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this piece of code:

```
$array[] = ['Name' => 'aa', 'Surname' => 'bb'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Values['name'] = 'aa';
$Values['surname'] = 'bb';
```

You can also throw away the existing array and replace it with a new one....

```
$Values=array('name'=>'aa', 'surname'=>'bb');
```

if there was data in the a\array beforehand and it is not referenced elsewhere, the memory will be freed.

You can also append a new array to an existing array using array_merge()

```
$Values=array_merge($Values, array('name'=>'aa', 'surname'=>'bb'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// empty array
$array = [];

// new array that we want to add to $array
$tmp = array(1,2,3);

// add $tmp to $array
$array[] = $tmp; 

// display the result
print_r($array);
```